# Python: Operating on separate types

Tags: python, exception, operator-overloading

I'm working as a free time project on a vector class in Python, to test myself. People with enough math background know that a vector can be multiplied by a scalar; 2 * (1, 2) = (2 * 1, 2 * 2) = (2, 4).

This is simple enough to do in, say, C#. `public static operator *(int scalar, Vector vector)` and go on to define it. But when I try to do the most obvious route in Python, it throws a TypeError at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Vector'
```

This is also raised when I reverse the order of the operands to `Vector * scalar`.

Now, I know that, in Python, iterables such as strings can be multiplied: e.g. "abc" * 2 yields "abcabc". My question is: is this only an inherent feature of the language, or is there a way to write multi-type operators?

The code:

```
class Vector:
        def __init__(self, *contents):
            self.__c = contents

        def __iter__(self):
            return iter(self.__c)

        def __add__(u, v):
            exceptIfUnequal(u, v, "add") # <-- This is just a method that will raise an error if the vectors are unequal, it's unimportant to us
            return Vector(*[a + b for a, b in zip(u, v)])

        def __sub__(u, v):
            exceptIfUnequal(u, v, "subtract")
            return a + (-b)

        def __neg__(u):
            return Vector(-a for a in u)

        def __mult__(k, u):
            return Vector(*[k * a for a in u])
#I'm aware that logistically, k and u will need to be reversed if I want to reverse the order

        def __len__(u):
            return len(u.__c)

        def __str__(self):
            s = "<" + "{}, " * (len(self.__c) - 1) + "{}>"
            return s.format(*self.__c)
```

So is there anything I can do to make this work? Or is it simply impossible?

**EDIT**: Wouldn't you know it, it was a silly mistake. The proper Python multiplication is `__mul__`, not - as I had written - `__mult__` -- with a *t*. But even more particularly, the item I wanted was `__rmul__`, which allows me to multiply in scalar * vector order.

Comment: It's `_mul_`, I believe, not `_mult_`.

Comment: You simply misspelt the method name. You also want to implement `__rmult__` here, for the `int * Vector` operation. You also want to stick to using `self` for the first argument.

Comment: Thanks much, Martijn! Now I feel kind of silly. But I'm glad you bring up rmult, because that's *exactly* what I need! Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work, you just have the wrong method name. It should be `__mul__`.

Although I think it's a little more nuanced if you want to support both `int * Vector` and `Vector * Vector`. You're going to need to add a bit more to the method for that.

Read here for more info https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types